# PowerShell Publish-Module is already used for a different item on the specified repository

Tags: powershell

I've already published with the `Publish-Module` many modules but suddenly I get this message only for PSGallery

```
The specified name '$moduleName' is already used for a different item on the specified repository 'PSGallery'. Run 'Find-Script -Name
```

$moduleName -Repository PSGallery' to check whether the specified name '$moduleName' is already taken.

where $moduleName is the name of the module. The PowerShell I use is

```
Publish-Module -Path $path -NuGetApiKey $key -Repository PSGallery -WhatIf
```

`Find-Module` reports that $moduleName is indeed a module.
On PowerShell gallery it presents the artificat as a module
Same `Publish-Module` works for any other PSRepository.

Any ideas anyone?

**Update 1**

I used Fiddler to compare the data flow between two modules.

**Publish-Module** at some point executes this (The name of the module with the problem is ISHDeploy.12.0.0)

```
https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2/items/psscript/FindPackagesById()?id='ISHDeploy.12.0.0'&$skip=0&$top=40
```

and returns

```
<id>https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2/items/psscript/Packages(Id='ISHDeploy.12.0.0',Version='0.1')</id>
        <category term="NuGetGallery.V2FeedPackage" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" />
        <link rel="edit" title="V2FeedPackage" href="Packages(Id='ISHDeploy.12.0.0',Version='0.1')" />
        <title type="text">ISHDeploy.12.0.0</title>
        <summary type="text"/>
        <updated>2016-08-01T18:36:38Z</updated>
        <author>
            <name>SDL plc</name>
        </author>
        <link rel="edit-media" title="V2FeedPackage" href="Packages(Id='ISHDeploy.12.0.0',Version='0.1')/$value" />
        <content type="application/zip" src="https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2/package/ISHDeploy.12.0.0/0.1.0" />
        <m:properties>
            <d:Version>0.1</d:Version>
            <d:NormalizedVersion>0.1.0</d:NormalizedVersion>
            <d:Copyright>SDL plc. All rights reserved.</d:Copyright>
            <d:Created m:type="Edm.DateTime">2016-06-24T13:11:21.6</d:Created>
            <d:Dependencies/>
            <d:Description>Deployment automation module for SDL Knowledge Center Content Manager 12.0.0 (LiveContent Architect, Trisoft InfoShare)</d:Description>
            <d:DownloadCount m:type="Edm.Int32">33</d:DownloadCount>
            <d:GalleryDetailsUrl>https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ISHDeploy.12.0.0/0.1.0</d:GalleryDetailsUrl>
            <d:IconUrl m:null="true" />
            <d:IsLatestVersion m:type="Edm.Boolean">true</d:IsLatestVersion>
            <d:IsAbsoluteLatestVersion m:type="Edm.Boolean">true</d:IsAbsoluteLatestVersion>
            <d:IsPrerelease m:type="Edm.Boolean">false</d:IsPrerelease>
            <d:Language m:null="true" />
            <d:Published m:type="Edm.DateTime">2016-06-24T13:11:21.6</d:Published>
            <d:PackageHash>0BsR7SQjEe7q5XO0IJqMOTS5iySLVYSzUFqHte4Hjng6Fxi+8BaUy3RNqmXs9Q53+QgrddI7e5Lij29kQlLS/g==</d:PackageHash>
            <d:PackageHashAlgorithm>SHA512</d:PackageHashAlgorithm>
            <d:PackageSize m:type="Edm.Int64">2723982</d:PackageSize>
            <d:ProjectUrl>https://sdl.github.io/ISHDeploy/12.0.0/Index.html</d:ProjectUrl>
            <d:ReportAbuseUrl>https://www.powershellgallery.com/package/ReportAbuse/ISHDeploy.12.0.0/0.1.0</d:ReportAbuseUrl>
            <d:ReleaseNotes>https://sdl.github.io/ISHDeploy/12.0.0/CHANGELOG.html</d:ReleaseNotes>
            <d:RequireLicenseAcceptance m:type="Edm.Boolean">false</d:RequireLicenseAcceptance>
            <d:Summary m:null="true" />
            <d:Tags m:null="true" />
            <d:Title m:null="true" />
            <d:VersionDownloadCount m:type="Edm.Int32">33</d:VersionDownloadCount>
            <d:MinClientVersion m:null="true" />
            <d:LastEdited m:type="Edm.DateTime">2016-06-24T14:14:56.217</d:LastEdited>
            <d:LicenseUrl m:null="true" />
            <d:LicenseNames m:null="true" />
            <d:LicenseReportUrl m:null="true" />
            <d:Workflows/>
            <d:ItemType>Module</d:ItemType>
            <d:FileList>ISHDeploy.12.0.0.nuspec|ISHDeploy.12.0.0.dll|ISHDeploy.12.0.0.dll-Help.xml|ISHDeploy.12.0.0.psd1|ISHDeploy.12.0.0.xml|Microsoft.Web.Administration.dll|System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll|amd64\sqlceca40.dll|amd64\sqlcecompact40.dll|amd64\sqlceer40EN.dll|amd64\sqlceme40.dll|amd64\sqlceqp40.dll|amd64\sqlcese40.dll|amd64\Microsoft.VC90.CRT\Microsoft.VC90.CRT.manifest|amd64\Microsoft.VC90.CRT\msvcr90.dll|amd64\Microsoft.VC90.CRT\README_ENU.txt|x86\sqlceca40.dll|x86\sqlcecompact40.dll|x86\sqlceer40EN.dll|x86\sqlceme40.dll|x86\sqlceqp40.dll|x86\sqlcese40.dll|x86\Microsoft.VC90.CRT\Microsoft.VC90.CRT.manifest|x86\Microsoft.VC90.CRT\msvcr90.dll|x86\Microsoft.VC90.CRT\README_ENU.txt</d:FileList>
            <d:Cmdlets>Disable-ISHUITranslationJob Enable-ISHUITranslationJob Disable-ISHUIQualityAssistant Enable-ISHUIQualityAssistant Disable-ISHUIContentEditor Enable-ISHUIContentEditor Disable-ISHExternalPreview Enable-ISHExternalPreview Set-ISHContentEditor Test-ISHContentEditor Get-ISHPackageFolderPath Set-ISHUIEventMonitorTab Move-ISHUIEventMonitorTab Remove-ISHUIEventMonitorTab Remove-ISHIntegrationSTSCertificate Set-ISHIntegrationSTSCertificate Save-ISHIntegrationSTSConfigurationPackage Set-ISHIntegrationSTSWSFederation Set-ISHIntegrationSTSWSTrust Save-ISHIntegrationDBSTSSQLServerConfiguration Clear-ISHDeploymentHistory Get-ISHDeployment Get-ISHDeploymentHistory Undo-ISHDeployment Set-ISHAPIWCFServiceCertificate</d:Cmdlets>
            <d:Functions/>
            <d:DscResources/>
            <d:RoleCapabilities/>
            <d:GUID>68ae5b26-edc0-453a-a720-ecc99d9b603e</d:GUID>
            <d:PowerShellVersion>3.0</d:PowerShellVersion>
            <d:PowerShellHostVersion m:null="true" />
            <d:DotNetFrameworkVersion>4.5</d:DotNetFrameworkVersion>
            <d:CLRVersion>4.0</d:CLRVersion>
            <d:ProcessorArchitecture m:null="true" />
            <d:CompanyName>SDL plc</d:CompanyName>
            <d:Owners>SDL</d:Owners>
        </m:properties>
    </entry>
</feed>
```

I compared with another module and I can't find any significant differences that could matter. It looks like something from this output halts the rest of the execution. Something in the xml is interpreted as a script entity although the xml clearly states that  this a module

```
<d:ItemType>Module</d:ItemType>
```

The manifest of the module to publish is

```
#
# Module manifest for module 'ISHDeploy.12.0.0'
#
# Generated by: SDL plc
#
# Generated on: 01-Aug-16
#

@{

# Script module or binary module file associated with this manifest.
RootModule = 'ISHDeploy.12.0.0'

# Version number of this module.
ModuleVersion = '0.2'

# ID used to uniquely identify this module
GUID = '68ae5b26-edc0-453a-a720-ecc99d9b603e'


# Author of this module
Author = 'SDL plc'

# Company or vendor of this module
CompanyName = 'SDL plc'

# Copyright statement for this module
Copyright = 'SDL plc. All rights reserved.'

# Description of the functionality provided by this module
Description = 'Deployment automation module for SDL Knowledge Center  Content Manager 12.0.0 (LiveContent Architect, Trisoft InfoShare)'


# Minimum version of the Windows PowerShell engine required by this module
PowerShellVersion = '3.0'

# Name of the Windows PowerShell host required by this module
# PowerShellHostName = ''

# Minimum version of the Windows PowerShell host required by this module
# PowerShellHostVersion = ''

# Minimum version of Microsoft .NET Framework required by this module
DotNetFrameworkVersion = '4.5'

# Minimum version of the common language runtime (CLR) required by this module
CLRVersion = '4.0'

# Processor architecture (None, X86, Amd64) required by this module
# ProcessorArchitecture = ''

# Modules that must be imported into the global environment prior to importing this module
# RequiredModules = @()

# Assemblies that must be loaded prior to importing this module
# RequiredAssemblies = @()

# Script files (.ps1) that are run in the caller's environment prior to importing this module.
# ScriptsToProcess = @()

# Type files (.ps1xml) to be loaded when importing this module
# TypesToProcess = @()

# Format files (.ps1xml) to be loaded when importing this module
# FormatsToProcess = @()

# Modules to import as nested modules of the module specified in RootModule/ModuleToProcess
# NestedModules = @()

# Functions to export from this module
FunctionsToExport = '*'

# Cmdlets to export from this module
CmdletsToExport = '*'

# Variables to export from this module
VariablesToExport = '*'

# Aliases to export from this module
AliasesToExport = '*'

# DSC resources to export from this module
# DscResourcesToExport = @()

# List of all modules packaged with this module
# ModuleList = @()

# List of all files packaged with this module
# FileList = @()

# Private data to pass to the module specified in RootModule/ModuleToProcess. This may also contain a PSData hashtable with additional module metadata used by PowerShell.
PrivateData = @{

    PSData = @{

        # Tags applied to this module. These help with module discovery in online galleries.
        # Tags = @()


        # A URL to the license for this module.
        # LicenseUri = ''

        # A URL to the main website for this project.
        # ProjectUri = ''

        # A URL to an icon representing this module.
        # IconUri = ''

        # ReleaseNotes of this module
        # ReleaseNotes = ''

    } # End of PSData hashtable

} # End of PrivateData hashtable

# HelpInfo URI of this module
HelpInfoURI = 'https://sdl.github.io/ISHDeploy/12.0.0/'


# Default prefix for commands exported from this module. Override the default prefix using Import-Module -Prefix.
# DefaultCommandPrefix = ''

}
```

I verified that the GUID is the same just in case it mattered for the gallery

**Conclusion**
I copy the summary from my answer bellow

Summary is that a module in gallery without tags is evaluated also a script and blocks the `Publish-Module`

Comment: [Link](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/f278fa69-75d7-4055-95a3-848e2e656f8f/publishmodule-throws-the-specified-name-modulename-is-already-used-for-a-different-item-on-the?forum=winserverpowershell) from PowerShell support forum

Answer (score 0):

I found what the problem was. It is actually a [bug](https://github.com/OneGet/oneget/issues/197) on the PackageManagement.

Summary is that a module in gallery without tags is evaluated also a script and blocks the `Publish-Module`